Cannot find type 'PhoneNumberKit' and Extra argument 'phoneNumberKit' in call Error in Flutter iOS App
I'm encountering two issues in my Flutter app when building for iOS:
Cannot find type 'PhoneNumberKit' in scope: I'm getting this error when trying to use the PhoneNumberKit library in my Flutter iOS project. It seems like the compiler is unable to find the PhoneNumberKit type.
Extra argument 'phoneNumberKit' in call: This error occurs when I try to instantiate or pass PhoneNumberKit in a function call. The function signature doesn't seem to accept this argument, although I'm following the documentation.
I tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Changing the CocoaPods version: I downgraded CocoaPods to an older version, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Manually changing the package version: I downgraded the PhoneNumberKit package to a lower version manually, and surprisingly, the app worked. However, I don't consider this a logical or sustainable solution, as it might lead to compatibility issues in the future.
I was expecting the app to build and run successfully using the latest versions of both CocoaPods and PhoneNumberKit without encountering these errors.

I found another issue.
it works for me.
I guess PhoneNumberKit make a wrong when upgrade. so both solution make a downgrade.
https://medium.com/@shahidbangashsi94/fix-for-swift-compiler-error-xcode-cannot-find-type-phonenumberkit-in-scope-b01daad3e452

If this question was open I would give a formal answer, but the compiler is telling you exactly what's going on. PhoneNumberKit is not a valid type in version 4 of the framework. The extra argument is telling you that that argument name isn't used anymore. Look at the release notes for version 4: https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit/releases/tag/4.0.0
The answer is to use PhoneNumberUtility as the type replacement and that argument name should now be utility. The issue is with the maintainers for the flutter plugin: https://github.com/natintosh/plugin_libphonenumber/pull/36

Remove Podfile.lock
in Podfile
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

    # Add This Line
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.7.6'

    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

run:
   pod install --repo-update
   flutter clean
   flutter build ios


The correct command is flutter build ios. I would edit it for you, but stupid site does not allow me to make 3 character edits...

its working thank you

Thank you, it's also working for the Swift project.
Don't worry about removing the Podfile.lock.

I copied and pasted the above code and caused The target [...] is declared multiple times error. I had to paste only pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.7.6'1 in podfile searching for target 'Runner' do

Problem is in libphonenumber_plugin v0.3.3 package. PhoneNumberKit package released version 4.0 a year ago, which introduced a breaking change renaming the API PhoneNumberKit to PhoneNumberUtility
So,
In my case 1 Answer did't worked. so This worked for me: I edited my
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/libphonenumber_plugin-0.3.3/ios/libphonenumber_plugin.podspec
libphonenumber_plugin.podspec:
s.dependency 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.6'
you can change this 3.6 version according to your system could br 3.7.6
pod install --repo-update
flutter build ios
I hope it will help others.

Heya, I don't see any ~>3.6?
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'PhoneNumberKit'

this is what I am seeing. How can I adjust it?
